# Make a shortcode echo in the middle of an URL in HREF

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The short code [mmjs-city] echoes the city the user is in.

I want to make a link that takes the user to a results page with the user's city as search term. Basically the URL should be the results page URL + the result of the shortcode (the city).

I tried to write it this way:

```
<a href="http://chusmix.com/?s=[mmjs-city]">Search for your city</a>
```

Normally I would just use PHP and assign the city to a value but I'm in a page not the theme and PHP doesn't work on pages for some reason, most likely It's possible but I don't know how. Anyway, anybody knows how could I do it? Thanks and merry christmas

Answer (score 0):

You can store city shortcode in session. In the result page, read session content to get city shortcode and make it to be a search term.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, could you please give me more info please?. Thanks

Comment: in login.php, read user's city shortcode and store in session, like '$_SESSION['city_shortcode'] = $record->rows['city_shortcode'];'. in result page, use session to get user's city shortcode to be a search term, like 'session_init(); ..... $query = "select * from `table` where `table`.`city_shortcode` = $_SESSION['city_shortcode']";'.